# Viewing DbgPrint messages in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, wdk, sysinternals, minifilter, debugview

I'm trying to write a MiniFilter driver. I've got Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 and WDK up and running on my Windows 8.1 box, along with a template from MS installed called "Filter Driver: Filesystem Mini-filter". I've made a fresh project with this template, enabling deployment to a remote (on my LAN) 8.1 VM with a small batch file to install the driver in lieu of the built-in driver installer (which I think isn't supported yet for minifilters).

In this template, there are many debug statements which are typedef'd to a call to DbgPrint. I would really like to be able to view these in DebugView from the SysInternals suite. Apparently all I needed to do would be to create in the registry a DWORD called `DEFAULT` set to 0xF under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter` according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551519(v=vs.85).aspx. But still, nothing shows up in DebugView. I launched it as an admin on the VM, and disabled capturing Win32.

I would assume the deployment tool from the WDK would have set up kernel debugging properly (it created a second user on my VM called WDKRemoteUser and ran `BCDEdit /debug` for me), but it doesn't seem to be enough. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is the test machine must be *started* with a debugger waiting to attach to it. When I do that, the kernel messages show up in the Visual Studio debugger and I assume in DebugView, too.

Answer (score 0):

Sysinternals DebugView does not need a "debug ON" machine, you have to use such setup for DebugView:

Start with admin rights and set on the following ones:
Capture Kernel, Enable Verbose Kernel Output, Pass-Through

Now close DebugView and reopen it as admin.

If you still can't see nothing there are the possibility that, the typedef'd DbgPrint() are not included into the deployed driver.